# how can I check a diagonal of my table for repeats?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to check if values in my table's diagonal are equal. How can I do that without checking each diagonal cell? I understand that I can use a loop to do that but I just can't figure out what loop to use.

```
table = [['1', ' ', '1'],
         [' ', '1', ' '],
         ['1', ' ', '1']]

if tb[0][0] == tb[1][1] == tb[2][2] != ' ' or tb[-1][0] == tb[-2][1] == tb[-3][2] != ' ':
    print(True)
```

Comment: @Norrius No they don't. There are 3 cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with arrays and matrices is easiest with [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/contents.html). So if this is an option for you, this is how you could go about checking the [diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) of your `table`:

```py
import numpy as np                                                                                                   
table = [['1', ' ', '1'],                                                                                            
         [' ', '1', ' '],                                                                                            
         ['1', ' ', '1']]                                                                                   
nptable = np.array(table)     
# now we can simply get the unique values in the diagonal:                                                                                                                                                                              
diag_values = np.unique(nptable.diagonal())
```

If you have a single value in `diag_values` then you know that all diagonal values are equal.

Now if you want to also check the other diagonal, you can use [np.fliplr](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr) and redo the same:

```py
diag_values = np.unique(np.fliplr(nptable).diagonal())
```

---

If you want to stick to lists then you could loop over the rows of `table` until you encounter a change if the value of the diagonal:

```py
diag_val = table[0][0]
for i, row in enumerate(table):
    if row[i] != diag_val:  # row[i] is basically table[i][i]
        print(f'diagonal value changes in row {i=}.')
        break  # we stop the loop as we encoutered a change
```

Checking the other diagonal is just as easy, simply access the element `-i-1` instead of element `i` in each row:

```py
diag_val = table[0][-1]
for i, row in enumerate(table):
    if row[-i-1] != diag_val:
        print(f'diagonal value changes in row {i=}.')
        break  # we stop the loop as we encoutered a change
```

Or, if the value in both cases should be the same, say `diag_val='1'`, you can do it in one go:

```py
diag_val = '1'
for i, row in enumerate(table):
    if row[i] != diag_val or row[-i-1] != diag_val:
        print(f'diagonal value changes in row {i=}.')
        break  # we stop the loop as we encoutered a change
```

*Hope that helped!*

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy.diagonal()` to get all the elements whether on the first or the second diagonal and then compare all the elements to satisfy the condition using `numpy.all()`

```
import numpy as np

mtx = np.array([['2', ' ', '1'],
                [' ', '1', ' '],
                ['1', ' ', '3']])


first_diag = mtx.diagonal()
second_diag = (np.fliplr(mtx)).diagonal()

result = np.all(second_diag == '1')

if result:
    print("all the elements in the diagonal are equal to one")
else:
    print("not all elements in the diagonal are equal")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do this is to extract the values of both diagonals as sets and then check if: a) the sets are equal and b) their size is 1.

```
main_diag = {row[ i] for i, row in enumerate(tb)}
anti_diag = {row[-i] for i, row in enumerate(tb, start=1)}

if main_diag == anti_diag and len(main_diag) == 1:
    print('All values along both diagonals are the same.')
```

Comment: The type of `main_diag` is `set`, created by the `set comprehension` on the right hand side. The set comprehension can be interpreted like a for loop that loops over `enumerate(tb)` and then adds `row[i]` to the to-be-constructed set.